# How to use fslint to mass delete or mass merge duplicate files with command line?

Tags: command-line, duplicate-files

Using FSlint terminal or command line options, is there a command to mass delete (all but the first of the group) or mass merge (with symlinks) all files within a directory?

Answer (score 0):

I found it using the command [`findup`](http://booki.flossmanuals.net/fslint/ch004_duplicates)

to merge all the duplicated files within a directory

> When -m is specified any found duplicates will be merged (using
>   hardlinks)

```
sudo /usr/share/fslint/fslint/findup -m -f <directory>
```

to delete all the duplicated files within a directory

> When -d is specified any found duplicates will be deleted (leaving
>   just 1)

```
sudo /usr/share/fslint/fslint/findup -d -f <directory>
```

Option `-f` list the files